# Partial least squares regression in R: why is PLS on standardized data not equivalent to maximizing correlation?

Tags: r, regression, partial-least-squares

I am very new in partial least squares (PLS) and I try to understand the output of the R function `plsr()` in the `pls` package. Let us simulate data and run the PLS:

```
library(pls)
n <- 50
x1 <- rnorm(n); xx1 <- scale(x1) 
x2 <- rnorm(n); xx2 <- scale(x2)
y <- x1 + x2 + rnorm(n,0,0.1); yy <- scale(y)
p <- plsr(yy ~ xx1+xx2, ncomp=1)
```

I was expecting that the following numbers $a$ and $b$

```
> ( w <- loading.weights(p) )

Loadings:
    Comp 1
xx1 0.723 
xx2 0.690 

               Comp 1
SS loadings       1.0
Proportion Var    0.5
> a <- w["xx1",]
> b <- w["xx2",]
> a^2+b^2
[1] 1
```

are calculated in order to maximize

```
> cor(y, a*xx1+b*xx2)
          [,1]
[1,] 0.9981291
```

but this is not exactly the case:

```
> f <- function(ab){
+ a <- ab[1]; b <- ab[2]
+ cor(y, a*xx1+b*xx2)
+ }
> optim(c(0.7,0.6), f, control=list(fnscale=-1))
$par
[1] 0.7128259 0.6672870

$value
[1] 0.9981618
```

Is it a numerical error, or do I misunderstand the nature of $a$ and $b$ ?

I would also like to know what are these coefficients:

```
> p$coef
, , 1 comps

           yy
xx1 0.6672848
xx2 0.6368604
```

**EDIT**: Now I see what `p$coef` is:

```
> x <- a*xx1+b*xx2
> coef(lm(yy~0+x))
        x 
0.9224208 
> coef(lm(yy~0+x))*a
        x 
0.6672848 
> coef(lm(yy~0+x))*b
        x 
0.6368604
```

So I think I'm right about the nature of $a$ and $b$.

**EDIT:** In view of the comments given by @chl I feel my question is not clear enough, so let me provide more details.  In my example there is a vector $Y$ of responses and a two-columns matrix $X$ of predictors and I use the normalized version $\tilde Y$ of $Y$ and the normalized version $\tilde X$ of $X$ (centered and divided by standard deviations). The definition of the first PLS component $t_1$ is $t_1 = a \tilde X_1 + b \tilde X_2$ with $a$ and $b$ chosen in order to have a maximal value of the inner product $\langle t_1, \tilde Y \rangle$. **Hence it is equivalent to maximizing the correlation between $t_1$ and $Y$, isn't it ?**

Comment: PLS regression maximises factor scores (which are computed as the product of raw data with loadings vector(s)) *covariance*, not *correlation* (as is done in Canonical Correlation Analysis). There's a good overview of the `pls` package and PLS regression in this [JSS paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v18/i02/).

Comment: Since all the vectors are centered and normalized, covariance is correlation, isn't it ? Sorry but the JSS paper is too much technical for a beginner.

Comment: In general, there's an asymmetrical deflation process (resulting from the regression of linear combination of one block onto linear combination of the other) that complicates things a bit. I provided some schematic picture in [this response](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4536/930). Hervé Abdi gave some [general overview](http://www.utdallas.edu/~herve/Abdi-PLS-pretty.pdf) of PLS regression, and Wegelin's [Survey of Partial Least Squares (PLS) Methods](http://bit.ly/y7MnHA) is quite useful too. At this point, I should probably convert all those comments to an answer...

Comment: In my example there is a vector $Y$ of responses and a two-columns matrix $X$ of predictors and I use the normalized version $\tilde Y$ of $Y$ and the normalized version $\tilde X$ of $X$ (centered and divided by standard deviations). My definition of the first PLS component $t_1$ is $t_1 = a \tilde X_1 + b \tilde X_2$ with $a$ and $b$ chosen in order to have a maximal value of the scalar product $\langle t_1, \tilde Y \rangle$. Isn't it the good definition ?

Comment: Sorry, @Stéphane, because my comments above did not take into account the fact that you only requested one component (so deflation doesn't play a critical role here). However, it seems that your optimization function doesn't impose unit norm weight vectors, such that $a^2+b^2\neq 1$ in the end. (btw, `?coef.mvr` will give you more information on what those 'coefficients' are, but you already discovered that yourself apparently.)

Comment: Yes but the condition $a^2+b^2=1$ is not restricitve (dividing by the Euclidean norm of $(a,b)$) Thanks

Comment: Let me some time to write a more considered response (I already drafted one but I'll be very busy today).

Comment: @Stephane, here is perhaps another footnote to this old question of yours: if you *whiten* the data instead of simply standardizing it, then PLS will indeed be equivalent to maximizing correlation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

PLS regression relies on iterative algorithms (e.g., NIPALS, SIMPLS). Your description of the main ideas is correct: we seek one (PLS1, one response variable/multiple predictors) or two (PLS2, with different modes, multiple response variables/multiple predictors) vector(s) of weights, $u$ (and $v$), say, to form linear combination(s) of the original variable(s) such that the covariance between Xu and Y (Yv, for PLS2) is maximal. Let us focus on extracting the first pair of weights associated to the first component. Formally, the criterion to optimize reads
$$\max\text{cov}(Xu, Yv).\qquad (1)$$
In your case, $Y$ is univariate, so it amounts to maximize
$$\text{cov}(Xu, y)\equiv \text{Var}(Xu)^{1/2}\times\text{cor}(Xu, y)\times\text{Var}(y)^{1/2},\quad st. \|u\|=1.$$
Since $\text{Var}(y)$ does not depend on $u$, we have to maximise $\text{Var}(Xu)^{1/2}\times\text{cor}(Xu, y)$. Let's consider `X=[x_1;x_2]`, where data are individually standardized (I initially made the mistake of scaling your linear combination instead of $x_1$ and $x_2$ separately!), so that $\text{Var}(x_1)=\text{Var}(x_2)=1$; however, $\text{Var}(Xu)\neq 1$ and depends on $u$. In conclusion, *maximizing the correlation between the latent component and the response variable will not yield the same results*.

I should thank [Arthur Tenenhaus](http://www.supelec.fr/361_p_10075/arthur-tenenhaus.html) who pointed me in the right direction.

Using unit weight vectors is not restrictive and some packages (`pls. regression` in [plsgenomics](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plsgenomics/), based on code from Wehrens's earlier package `pls.pcr`) will return unstandardized weight vectors (but with latent components still of norm 1), if requested. But most of PLS packages will return standardized $u$, including the one you used, notably those implementing the SIMPLS or NIPALS algorithm; I found a good overview of both approaches in Barry M. Wise's presentation, [Properties of Partial Least Squares (PLS) Regression, and differences between Algorithms](http://www.eigenvector.com/Docs/Wise_pls_properties.pdf), but the [chemometrics](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chemometrics/index.html) vignette offers a good discussion too (pp. 26-29). Of particular importance as well is the fact that most PLS routines (at least the one I know in R) assume that you provide unstandardized variables because centering and/or scaling is handled internally (this is particularly important when doing cross-validation, for example).

Given the constraint $u'u=1$, the vector $u$ is found to be $$u=\frac{X'y}{\|X'y\|}.$$

Using a little simulation, it can be obtained as follows:

```
set.seed(101)
X <- replicate(2, rnorm(100))
y <- 0.6*X[,1] + 0.7*X[,2] + rnorm(100)
X <- apply(X, 2, scale)
y <- scale(y)

# NIPALS (PLS1)
u <- crossprod(X, y)
u <- u/drop(sqrt(crossprod(u)))         # X weights
t  <- X%*%u
p <- crossprod(X, t)/drop(crossprod(t)) # X loadings
```

You can compare the above results (`u=[0.5792043;0.8151824]`, in particular) with what R packages would give. E.g., using NIPALS from the [chemometrics](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chemometrics/index.html) package (another implementation that I know is available in the [mixOmics](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixOmics/index.html) package), we would obtain:

```
library(chemometrics)
pls1_nipals(X, y, 1)$W  # X weights [0.5792043;0.8151824]
pls1_nipals(X, y, 1)$P  # X loadings
```

Similar results would be obtained with `plsr` and its default kernel PLS algorithm:

```
> library(pls)
> as.numeric(loading.weights(plsr(y ~ X, ncomp=1)))
[1] 0.5792043 0.8151824
```

In all cases, we can check that $u$ is of length 1.

Provided you change your function to optimize to one that reads

```
f <- function(u) cov(y, X%*%(u/sqrt(crossprod(u))))
```

and normalize `u` afterwards (`u <- u/sqrt(crossprod(u))`), you should be closer to the above solution.

*Sidenote*: As criterion (1) is equivalent to 
$$\max u'X'Yv,$$
$u$ can be found as the left singular vector from the SVD of $X'Y$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue:

```
svd(crossprod(X, y))$u
```

In the more general case (PLS2), a way to summarize the above is to say that the first PLS canonical vectors are the best approximation of the covariance matrix of X and Y in both directions.

### References

1. Tenenhaus, M (1999). [L'approche PLS](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/RSA/RSA_1999__47_2/RSA_1999__47_2_5_0/RSA_1999__47_2_5_0.pdf). *Revue de Statistique Appliquée*, 47(2), 5-40.
2. ter Braak, CJF and de Jong, S (1993). [The objective function of partial least squares regression](http://enpub.fulton.asu.edu/cseml/06summer/OBJ_DIS.pdf). *Journal of Chemometrics*, 12, 41–54.
3. Abdi, H (2010). [Partial least squares regression and projection on latent structure regression (PLS Regression)](http://www.utdallas.edu/~herve/abdi-wireCS-PLS2010.pdf). *Wiley Interdisciplinary Reviews: Computational Statistics*, 2, 97-106.
4. Boulesteix, A-L and Strimmer, K (2007). [Partial least squares: a versatile tool for the analysis of high-dimensional genomic data](http://bib.oxfordjournals.org/content/8/1/32.full). *Briefings in Bioinformatics*, 8(1), 32-44.

Comment: Thanks chl. I will read your answer whenever possible (and surely upvote and click the check mark !)

Comment: I have just read your answer - congratulations and thank you very much.