# Statistical test for weighted sum of random variables?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

What methods would you recommend for testing whether a variable Y is the weighted sum of n, not necessarily independent, variables? Only m < n of these variables are known.

The problem is easy if the variables are independent. (In my setting their co-variance is close to zero).

Comment: Please add more information. Are we talking about an exact weighted sum or is there an error term? Are the two variables that sum up to Y observed?

Comment: Just edited the text to make my meaning clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered a multiple regression analysis with your m predictors and Y as the dependent variable?  If so, why are you not comfortable with that approach?  If not, would that be of help to you?

Comment: My fear was the (weak) dependency. I noticed a detailed answer here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4517/regression-with-multiple-dependent-variables so, I guess my question is a duplicate.