# Multiple dependant variable in multiple linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multivariate-regression

I have **8 independant variables** and **2 dependant variables**.Iam using multiple linear regression.I just finished the regression topic so iam a starter in this.Can anyone say how to approach this one??

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of answers to a similar question below.  It probably depends on what the dependent variables are.  I would start by running them in two separate regressions and compare them.  Can they be combined logically?  For instance if your DVs were variable and fixed costs, they could be combined into total costs.

Anyhoo...these guys sound a lot smarter than me:
[Regression with multiple dependent variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4517/regression-with-multiple-dependent-variables)